# customization of theorem, lemma, definition, ... in ieeeconf

Tags: theorems, amsthm, ieeeconf

I am working with following `ieeeconf`-based template:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  % Comment this line out if you need a4paper

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              % This command is only needed if 
                                                          % you want to use the \thanks command
\overrideIEEEmargins                                      % Needed to meet printer requirements.

\usepackage{graphics} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
\usepackage{epsfig} % for postscript graphics files
\usepackage{mathptmx} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath} % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}

\title{\LARGE \bf
My Title*
}

\author{Guy$^{1}$
\thanks{*This work was not supported by any organization}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{$^{1}$Guy is with Hell,
        {\tt\small guy@hell.edu}}%
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}

ABSTRACT

\end{abstract}

\section{INTRODUCTION}


\begin{thm}
My theorem is blaw.
\proof Here is the proof.
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}
My lemma is blaw.
\proof Here is the proof.
\end{lem}

\begin{defn}
Look at my definition.
\end{defn}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{c1} G. O. Young, ÒSynthetic structure of industrial plastics (Book style with paper title and editor),Ó    in Plastics, 2nd ed. vol. 3, J. Peters, Ed.  New York: McGraw-Hill, 1964, pp. 15Ð64.


\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

As you can compile the MWE, I don't like the formation and style of my logic environments, and I'd like to change them to be shown something like below:

[image]

[image]

(All environments needs to be bold, with numerals to address them. Lemma and theorem must be ended with a black square and so on.)

But as I try to customize the style with `\newtheoremstyle{plain}` and using `amsthm` package, an error will be raised as following:

**! LaTeX Error: Command \proof already defined.**

Update 1: Adding `\let\proof\relax` did not lead to error-free compilation.

Update 2: @egreg's answer does still throw the error on my machine, as following:

[image]

Update 3: Here is my `IEEEconf` version from log file: `Document Class: ieeeconf 2016/4/23 revision V1.6b by Pradeep Misra`

Comment: Try with `\let\proof\relax \usepackage{amsthm}` ...

Comment: @Werner: It didn't work, appropriately. Please find the update.

Comment: I can compile your document if I remove `\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts` and `\overrideIEEEmargins` from the preamble and add `\usepackage{amsthm}`. That is, I can add `\usepackage{amsthm}` without raising the error you mention.

Comment: @Werner: The problem is not with adding `\usepackage{amsthm}` or removing those two commands from the preamble (the file will be compiled perfectly), but adding `\newtheoremstyle{plain}` for final customization is the thing that does not work, though.

Comment: You must not use `\proof`, but `\begin{proof}...\end{proof}` *outside* the theorem statement.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks! You kindly resolved one aspect of what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The class name is `IEEEconf` with the first part capitalized. Calling it `ieeeconf` works on Windows, but not on other systems
2. The `epsf` package should not be used in new documents. If the people at the conference tell you to, they are lagging twenty years behind.
3. Don't use `\bf` in any document. Formatting instructions like `\LARGE` in the argument to `\title` will just annoy the copy editors.
4. Loading `times` after `mathptmx` is redundant (and maybe even dangerous).
5. `\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts` and `\overrideIEEEmargins` aren't defined in the current version of `IEEEconf`.
6. Loading `amsthm` in an `IEEEconf` class is perfectly fine.

The main problem is how you are calling `proof`: it should not be

```
\begin{thm}
My theorem is blaw.
\proof Here is the proof.
\end{thm}
```

but

```
\begin{thm}
My theorem is blaw.
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
Here is the proof.
\end{proof}
```

Here's an example, massaged to be compilable.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, conference]{IEEEconf}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}

\title{My Title*}

\author{Guy$^{1}$
\thanks{*This work was not supported by any organization}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{$^{1}$Guy is with Hell, {\tt\small guy@hell.edu}}%
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}

ABSTRACT

\end{abstract}

\section{INTRODUCTION}


\begin{thm}
My theorem is blaw.
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
Here is the proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{lem}
My lemma is blaw.
\end{lem}
\begin{proof}
Here is the proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{defn}
Look at my definition.
\end{defn}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{c1} G. O. Young, ÒSynthetic structure of industrial plastics (Book style with paper title and editor),Ó    in Plastics, 2nd ed. vol. 3, J. Peters, Ed.  New York: McGraw-Hill, 1964, pp. 15Ð64.


\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I `copied and pasted` your answer to be compiled, completely, But the proof's issue does still exist! (Please find update 2)

Comment: @Roboticist I feel you have quite an old version of `IEEEconf.cls`. Where did you get it?

Comment: Actually, I'd reinstalled it right now from my `MikTeX Package Manager`, but nothing's changed. (The new installation date is 2017-01-14, now). It must be latest version, reasonably.

Comment: Please, add to your question the data about the class which you find at the top of the log file: I have `Document Class: IEEEconf 2009/04/05 v1.4 IEEE Computer Society 8.5x11" conference proceedings` and this is the one in TeX Live and MiKTeX. If you have something different, then you have a bogus class calling itself `ieeeconf.cls` and it's important to know where you got it from.

Comment: Mine is `Document Class: ieeeconf 2016/4/23 revision V1.6b by Pradeep Misra`, added to the question. Is this a bogus one?!

Comment: @Roboticist Yes. It's definitely not the official IEEEconf on CTAN. Sorry, but without knowing where you got it, it's impossible to help. Unfortunately, it seems there's a plethora of `ieeeconf.cls` around the Web.

Comment: I always use package manager to update my packages, from an official repository of MikTeX... How has this bogus file resides in my MiKTeX?!... What should I do now to get rid of that?... Uninstalling and reinstalling or something?...

Comment: @Roboticist Before the line where you got the information about the class there should be the path to it: can you please show it?

Comment: Wow!!! Thanks a bunch... That was the problem. Compiler was using a file other than the right one from a folder on my system. I'd deleted that and now compiler uses the official one from TeX folders and your solution does work like a charm (`AS ALWAYS`)!

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. My solution was to add `\let\proof\relax \let\endproof\relax` before `\usepackage{amsthm}`.

**Side note:**
The official version of *ieeeconf* can be found on [Paper Plaza](http://css.paperplaza.net/conferences/support/tex.php). It seems that the version `IEEEconf 2009/04/05 v1.4 IEEE Computer Society 8.5x11` is only for the computer science society and the style differs from the version I am referring to. In the file *ieeeconf.cls* there is a section called *ENVIRONMENTS* where you can see which commands are being defined.